# Select the previous month

Tags: mysql

```
 WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= '2016-12-01' AND
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date <= '2016-12-31'
```

How to select data for previous month, not current day - 30 day? Forexample, in any day of january, its always from 1dec to 31dec.

Comment: not current day mean what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
WHERE order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) and
      order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day)
```

Note that the expression:  `date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day)` returns the first day of the current month.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2016-11-01 |
| 2016-11-04 |
| 2016-11-06 |
| 2016-11-07 |
| 2016-11-09 |
| 2016-11-10 |
| 2016-11-12 |
| 2016-11-13 |
| 2016-11-14 |
| 2016-11-15 |
| 2016-11-16 |
| 2016-11-17 |
| 2016-11-18 |
| 2016-11-19 |
| 2016-11-20 |
| 2016-11-21 |
| 2016-11-22 |
| 2016-11-23 |
| 2016-11-24 |
| 2016-11-25 |
| 2016-11-26 |
| 2016-11-28 |
| 2016-12-01 |
| 2016-12-03 |
| 2016-12-04 |
| 2016-12-07 |
| 2016-12-11 |
| 2016-12-13 |
| 2016-12-15 |
| 2016-12-18 |
| 2016-12-19 |
| 2016-12-22 |
| 2016-12-25 |
| 2016-12-28 |
| 2017-01-01 |
| 2017-01-04 |
| 2017-01-07 |
| 2017-01-11 |
| 2017-01-14 |
| 2017-01-15 |
| 2017-01-16 |
| 2017-01-19 |
+------------+

SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE dt BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01') 
              AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2016-12-01 |
| 2016-12-03 |
| 2016-12-04 |
| 2016-12-07 |
| 2016-12-11 |
| 2016-12-13 |
| 2016-12-15 |
| 2016-12-18 |
| 2016-12-19 |
| 2016-12-22 |
| 2016-12-25 |
| 2016-12-28 |
+------------+
```